# Barra de Progresso em Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Galera, tennho uma barra que funciona da seguinte forma, quando o meu scroll estiver em cima da div das barras elas vão começar a encher. eu fiz o css, mas não tô conseguindo fazer o Jquery, alguma dica?

HTML:

```
    <label for="barra"><h2>HTML </h2><span id="porcentagemhtml"></span></label>
    <div class="container-barra">
      <div class="barra"></div>
    </div>

    <label for="barra"><h2>CSS </h2><span id="porcentagecss"></span></label>
    <div class="container-barra">
      <div class="barra"></div>
    </div>

    <label for="barra"><h2>JAVASCRIPT </h2><span id="porcentagemjs"></span></label>
    <div class="container-barra">
      <div class="barra"></div>
    </div>

    <label for="barra"><h2>PHP </h2><span id="porcentagemphp"></span></label>
    <div class="container-barra">
      <div class="barra"></div>
    </div>

    <label for="barra"><h2>SQL </h2><span id="porcentagemsql"></span></label>
    <div class="container-barra">
      <div class="barra"></div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.container-barra{
  width: 100%;
  border: 0.1px solid;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.barra{
  width: 0%;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 15px;

}
```

jQUERY:

```
$(document).scroll(function(){      
   var posicao = window.pageYOffset;
   if(posicao>=1287){
     setInterval(encheBarra, 30);
   } 
});
// Chamada da Função
function encheBarra(){

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function move(idElem) {
  var elem = document.getElementById(idElem); 
  var width = 0;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
  function frame() {
    if (width >= 100) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      width++; 
      elem.style.width = width + '%'; 
    }
  }
}
var auxPhp = 0;
var auxSql = 0;

$(window).on('scroll', function(){
    if(isScrolledIntoView('#barraPhp') && auxPhp == 0){
        move('barraPhp');
        auxPhp = 1;
    }
    if(isScrolledIntoView('#barraSql') && auxSql == 0){
        move('barraSql');
        auxSql = 1;
    }
});
function isScrolledIntoView(elem){
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

    return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}
```

```css
.container-barra{
  width: 100%;
  border: 0.1px solid;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.barra{
  width: 0%;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 15px;

}
```

```html
<label for="barra"><h2>HTML </h2><span id="porcentagemhtml"></span></label>
    <div class="container-barra">
      <div class="barra" id="barraHtml" ></div>
    </div>
    <button onclick="move('barraHtml')">Click Me</button> 

    <label for="barra"><h2>CSS </h2><span id="porcentagecss"></span></label>
    <div class="container-barra">
      <div class="barra"></div>
    </div>

    <label for="barra"><h2>JAVASCRIPT </h2><span id="porcentagemjs"></span></label>
    <div class="container-barra">
      <div class="barra"></div>
    </div>

    <label for="barra"><h2>PHP </h2><span id="porcentagemphp"></span></label>
    <div class="container-barra">
      <div class="barra" id="barraPhp"></div>
    </div>

    <label for="barra"><h2>SQL </h2><span id="porcentagemsql"></span></label>
    <div class="container-barra">
      <div class="barra" id="barraSql"></div>
    </div>
    
   
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Eu fiz um exemplo de como você conseguiria encher a barra, clique no botão `Click Me` para ver o exemplo funcionando. Só não entendi muito bem a parte do scroll, você quer que qnd essas barras ficarem visíveis para o usuário elas começarem a encher? Se sim, eu fiz dessa forma para as barras de progresso de php e sql.

Comment: Sim, tipo, quando eu chegasse na posição 1287 da tela, a barra enchesse. Eu consegui fazer em Javascript com o Ex da w3c , mas não em Jquery